# Cycling order in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting

Having following `Foo` table:

```
id | name    | group
===|=========|======
1  | "John"  | 1
2  | "Paul"  | 1
3  | "Marry" | 1
4  | "Josh"  | 1
5  | "Mike"  | 2
6  | "Kevin" | 2
7  | "Ramon" | 2
8  | "Kim"   | 2
9  | "Henry" | 3
10 | "Susan" | 3
11 | "Greg"  | 3
12 | "Julie" | 3
```

I'd like to select it having cycling order on `group` field. 
For example, when I would like to select 6 rows, query should return:

```
id | name    | group
===|=========|======
1  | "John"  | 1
5  | "Mike"  | 2
10 | "Henry" | 3
2  | "Paul"  | 1
6  | "Kevin" | 2
11 | "Susan" | 3
```

**important** - there are unlimited `group`s in the table, so using `CASE` or any verbose function is pointless.

Is this possible using `MySQL`?

Comment: Will you have the same number of `1` and `2` and `3`?

Comment: @OscarPérez: *there are unlimited groups in the table*

Comment: For the love of humanity, don't call a column `group`!!

Comment: I know, in real db there's no `group` column, I named it here like this for ease of reading.

Answer (score 3):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;

CREATE TABLE foo
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,seq INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES
(1  ,"John"  ,1),
(2  ,"Paul"  ,1),
(3  ,"Marry" , 1),
(4  ,"Josh"  , 1),
(5  ,"Mike"  , 2),
(6  ,"Kevin" , 2),
(7  ,"Ramon" , 2),
(8  ,"Kim"   , 2),
(9  ,"Henry" , 3),
(10 ,"Susan" , 3),
(11 ,"Greg"  , 3),
(12 ,"Julie" , 3);

SELECT x.*
  FROM foo x
  JOIN foo y
    ON y.seq = x.seq AND y.id <= x.id
 GROUP
    BY x.id
 ORDER
    BY COUNT(*),seq LIMIT 6;
+----+-------+-----+
| id | name  | seq |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | John  |   1 |
|  5 | Mike  |   2 |
|  9 | Henry |   3 |
|  2 | Paul  |   1 |
|  6 | Kevin |   2 |
| 10 | Susan |   3 |
+----+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
  SELECT f1.*
    FROM Foo AS f1
ORDER BY   (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM Foo AS f3)
         * (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM Foo AS f2
             WHERE f2.group = 1
               AND f2.id < f1.id)
         + f1.group
```